# PHP - Autosize image according to data from JSON

Tags: php, json

i want autosize an image according to data from json. This data is updating and i need get a image that shows a list like this:
This list is according to JSON Data

Example:

```
NL: Anon1
EN: Anon3
ES: Anon9
```

Here's the code that i have:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");

$link = 'http://riddlematic.com/staff.json';
$f = file_get_contents($link);
$json = json_decode($f);

foreach ($json->mods as $key => $val) {
$q = strtoupper($key) . ': ' . implode(', ', $val);
}

$font  = "IMPACT.TTF";
$size  = 30;

$bbox   = imageftbbox($size, 0, $font, $q);



$width  = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
$height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];

$im    = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$green = imagecolorallocate($im, 60, 240, 60);

imagefttext($im, $size, 0, -$bbox[6], -$bbox[7], $green, $font, $q);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

EDIT: Currently JSON data is off but its like this:

```
{
 "map": {},
 "mod": {
   "br": [
     "Explanado"
   ],
   "de": [
     "Sweetphoenix"
   ]
   }
}'
```

Hope anyone help me 
pls

PS: m sorry double post

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Its shows just a one object.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
// header("Content-type: image/png");
    $link = base_url('staff.json');
$f = file_get_contents($link);
$json = json_decode($f);

$font  = "C:/xampp/htdocs/api/texb.ttf";
echo $font;
$size  = 30;
foreach ($json->mods as $key => $val) {
    $q = strtoupper($key) . ': ' . implode(', ', $val);
    $bbox   = imageftbbox($size, 0, $font, $q);



    $width  = $bbox[2] - $bbox[6];
    $height = $bbox[3] - $bbox[7];

    $im    = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $green = imagecolorallocate($im, 60, 240, 60);

    imagefttext($im, $size, 0, -$bbox[6], -$bbox[7], $green, $font, $q);
    imagepng($im, $key.'.png',9);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

I remove the header code ***header("Content-type: image/png");*** and put your image code inside the foreach loop after that I save every image generated ***imagepng($im, $key.'.png',9);***

Sorry I use my own FONT just replace it with your own.

Comment: Ty, but i dont need save it. I need group all images and do a list. I dont know if im explain correctly.

Comment: What kind of list?

Comment: Like this: http://image.prntscr.com/image/c3de4670de4d488a8fc7f2344c08da2c.png / PS: Anon are the Usernames.

Comment: Yeah, i want that